# Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio

Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

having this error in android studio when running react native app to install as release build
i have tried gradlew clean
invalid caches and restart
clean project

./gradlew assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets.

all the steps but not working